getting a "No module named 'torch'" error while trying to pip install mistral_inference
I am not using Conda, so the other big thread is not really helpful. I installed PyTorch with:
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu124

command from a PyTorch's website (it suits my parameters), but when I try to install a mistral_inference that depends on Torch it gives me an error that looks like this:
 PS C:\Users\admin> pip install mistral_inference
Collecting mistral_inference
  Using cached mistral_inference-1.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (14 kB)
Collecting fire>=0.6.0 (from mistral_inference)
  Using cached fire-0.7.0.tar.gz (87 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting mistral_common>=1.4.0 (from mistral_inference)
  Using cached mistral_common-1.4.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
Collecting pillow>=10.3.0 (from mistral_inference)
  Using cached pillow-10.4.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (9.3 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: safetensors>=0.4.0 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from mistral_inference) (0.4.4)
Collecting simple-parsing>=0.1.5 (from mistral_inference)
  Using cached simple_parsing-0.1.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.3 kB)
Collecting xformers>=0.0.24 (from mistral_inference)
  Using cached xformers-0.0.28.post1.tar.gz (7.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zjzruady\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 332, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zjzruady\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 302, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zjzruady\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 503, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-zjzruady\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 318, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 24, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I already encountered a problem like that a month ago, but I fixed it by properly installing torch using PyTorch instructions and the proper link (also some voodoo to replace missing files, but it was a different error), and I tried it again, but it said that requirement is already satisfied, so now I'm kinda clueless what to do.

Please provide the exact commands to recreate the error.

only thing im typing in the powershell is "pip install mistral_inference", i can edit the post to include the whole thing that it shows

@Alperino sorry didnt ping you the first time, new to posting and commenting here

Hello @Alperino, do you have several version of python installed on your machine or virtual environments ? It may be relevant because you used pip3 and then pip, so there is a possibility your installed pytorch on a different location than the one you're trying to install mistral onto.

@Lrx i think you wanted to adress your comment to me? if you did then kinda yes, i downloaded conda because of other big thread, but i did it just yesterday and i had torch installed before that, and i tried to pip install mistrel in powershell, so it shouldnt go to conda environments, so i dont think thats the issue

@wallstreet sorry for the confusion, yes the message was for you. The terminal used to launch pip install is not particularly linked to a specific interpreter, so actually, it might be the issue. What could have happened : torch was installed on your global python interpreter -> you installed conda -> Somehow it gets the default priority for the pip installs (on a base environment) -> mistral_inference was thus installed on a conda environment, and cannot access to your pytorch install. Have you try pip install pytorch and mistral at the same time, for verification purposes ?

@Lrx I tried doing it at the same time both with link from pytorch website and just pip install torch, in both cases it says that requirement is already satisfied and after that no module named torch. Also i encountered this issue before installing conda (i installed it trying to fix it) so i doubt thats the case, but idk what else could cause it

I got the error resolved by first installing xformers since it is not able to recognize the torch module which was already installed
pip3 install -U xformers --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu124

then try installing mistral_inference
pip3 install mistral-inference

